# How to create two flex containers, one growing its height with content, the other not?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm Looking to create two containers besides each other, taking up the entire width (distributed through `flex`) and having the same height. The left one should grow its height with its content, the right one should always be exactly *the same height* as the left one, scrolling it's content when necessary.

The structure looks like this. Currently the right column grows the left column (and parent container), which shouldn't happen. Obviously `max-height` doesn't have any effect here, as the reference is the parent `div`. How can I make this work?

```css
.container { 
  display: flex;
}
.col1 { 
  flex: 1;
  background: #999;
}
.col2 { 
  flex: 2;
  background: #F00;
  max-height: 100%; /* max-height should be height of left column */
  overflow: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1">
    this<br>
    div<br>
    should<br>
    grow<br>
    based<br>
    on<br>
    content
   </div>
  <div class="col2">
    this<br>
    div<br>
    should<br>
    never<br>
    exceed<br>
    the height<br>
    defined by the left one<br>
    (which happens with this row)<br>
    it should scroll instead
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because a flex-box will always be sized to its own inner content: in this case, what you want is to take all the content in `.col2` out of the document flow, so that it does not influence the sizing of the entire flexbox.

To do this, you will need to wrap the contents of `.col2` in a wrapper element that is absolutely positioned within `.col2`:

```css
.container { 
  display: flex;
}
.col1 { 
  flex: 1;
  background: #999;
}
.col2 { 
  flex: 2;
  background: #F00;
  position: relative;
}
.col2 .wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1">
    this<br>
    div<br>
    should<br>
    grow<br>
    based<br>
    on<br>
    content
   </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <div class="wrapper">
    this<br>
    div<br>
    should<br>
    never<br>
    exceed<br>
    the height<br>
    defined by the left one<br>
    (which happens with this row)<br>
    it should scroll instead
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**e*dit : Another similar answer was posted before mine, i do not think that another method could be used here***

---

You will need an extra wrapper to take the content off the flow. position:relative/absolute will work together to set the scroll bar when needed without being taken into account for the size of the main container.

Possible example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.col1 {
  flex: 1;
  background: #999;
}

.col2 {
  flex: 2;
  background: #F00;
  position: relative;
}

.col2>div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  /* max-height should be height of left column */
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1">
    this<br> div
    <br> should
    <br> grow
    <br> based
    <br> on
    <br> content
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <div class="buffer">this<br> div
      <br> should
      <br> never
      <br> exceed
      <br> the height<br> defined by the left one<br> (which happens with this row)<br> it should scroll instead
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```